# USB devices, where do their names come from

Tags: usb, device

when you insert a usb mouse, keyboard, etc... you get to see their name, make, model in the device manager.
Just like it happens for other devices like GPUs, etc...

I would like to understand (for USB devices):

1. Where exactely is that name stored?
2. Inside the device in some kind of IC?
3. Can I change it? How?

If I am saying/thinking wrong, correct me please.

Thx ;)

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot showing the information you are talking about, I might be able to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every USB device can optionally provide string descriptors to the operating system with its product name, and manufacturer name.  This is part of the USB specification, and it will be programmed into the device.  It will be very unlikely that you will be able to change it, unless the device is open source hardware.

Also, if there happens to be an INF file installed for the USB device in question on your system, that INF file can specify the name that will show up in the device manager.

Comment: I was trying to do that so I could change the name that pops up, when for example, you stick a USB mouse in the USB port, instead of something like "Logitech .... is being installed", it would have the name of my choice.
Thank you for clarifying this for me :)